# RPX/Janrain - using an image map instead of the widget

Tags: imagemap, janrain, rpxnow, rpx

I would like to use an image map for my Rpx/Janrain basic account instead of the widget they provide. I have tried looking through the javascript file, but it is minified so useless to me.

I just want the "login buttons" to be displayed in my header image with an area map and depending on the image area clicked launch in to the login for that service.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit late to the game but I will answer this for posterity. Unfortunately this isn't possible with the Basic app. Pro level and up allows you to customize your method of login. You would set janrain.settings.custom = true; in the settings in the head and use the janrain.engage.signin.triggerFlow(provider) function in the image map areas to kick off the various identity provider sign in pages.

See http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/widgets/social-sign-in-widget/users-guide/coding-the-widget-appearance/ for examples.